# Add custom class to radio button input

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

I'm trying to customise a dynamically generated form by adding images instead of radio buttons.

The output is :

```html
 <div class="customclass">
                <ul>
     <li><label><input type="radio" name="6da03fc5d368e675516b5dfc1d171e86fjfj" value="1"> Yes</label></li>
     <li><label><input type="radio" name="6da03fc5d368e675516b5dfc1d171e86fjfj" value="0"> No</label></li>
    </ul>
            </div>
```

This is the working code to add class based on radio button and value :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.propertyoptin input[type=radio][value=1]').addClass('form-control');
});​
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  A quick google search for "jquery, add class to elements" should return you some starting points.

Comment: please show us what you have done so far to accomplish your goal

Comment: How are you verifying that that "does not work"?  Also are the radio buttons generated dynamically on the page?

Comment: I've updated the original post,  I've got it working with the above.  But unsure how to apply it based on value so I can apply a class to value 1 and 0

Comment: Never mind,  Simpler than I thought :D

Answer (score 0):

Just a few tips:

- In that piece of JavaScript code you're using jQuery, if you want to do it with pure JavaScript you have to use another sentences (element.classList.add("textbox"); to add the class, for example)
- If you want to use jQuery you'll need to import its code (https://jquery.com/)